# Left adjoint of a forgetful functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Totally stuck at categories (I'm self-studying them, reading lecture notes from the course). I found the following problem in exercises:

> There is an evident forgetful functor
> $$U:\mathbf{Vect_k} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}.$$
> Show that this functor has a left-adjoint $F$ with a unit
> $$\eta_X : X \rightarrow UF(X).$$
> What property does the image of $\eta_X$ have within the vector space $F(X)$?

Do not really know where to start. Can you help please?

Comment: Show that $F$ assigns to each set $X$ the vector space with $X$ as a basis. $\eta_X$ is then the insertion of these generators.

Comment: Just a comment: left adjoints to forgetful functors often go under the heading "free". So, with this in mind, as Stefan suggests, the "free vector space" on a set seems like a good option.

Comment: Also note that there are many equivalent characterizations of adjointness. The definition I learned used a natural bijection between $X(x,Ga)$ and $A(Fx,a)$, where $F:X→A$ and $G:A→X$. But I think in most cases one uses the characterization via the universal arrows $η_x:x→GFx$ for each object $x\in X$. Here you have to show that a map $f:x→Ga$ there's a unique map $f':Fx→a$ such that $Gf'∘η_x=f$. The object function $F$ can then be extended to a functor $X→A$ in a unique way such that $η:x→GFx$ is a natural transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may read $U$ as the '*underlying set*' functor, and $F$ as the '*free*' functor. 
Note that the forgetful functor always has a left adjoint for each category of (all algebraic structures of the same kind).

In the case of vector spaces over $k$, the *free* vector space on a set $X$ is just a vector space of dimension $|X|$: we start out of the set $X$ and extend it by applying *freely* (meaning: only '*formally*') the given operations on the arising elements. So that, in the end, we arrive to the *free vector space* $F(X)$ of formal linear combinations of elements of $X$, which means that $X$ (mapped into the underlying set $UF(X)$ of $F(X)$ via $\eta_X$) is a *basis* in $F(X)$.

**Remark.** I like to permit arrows between objects of two distinct categories $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ (so called '*heteromorphisms*'), which together with the original arrows form a bigger category. In this case, we could define this bigger category as the disjoint union of ${\bf Set}$ and ${\bf Vect}_k$ plus all functions $A\to U(V)$ as heteromorphisms. 
Then, adjunction can be rephrased as

> Each object of $\bf A$ has a *reflection* in $\bf B$, and each object of $\bf B$ has a *coreflection* in $\bf A$.

Comment: You write "The forgetful functor always has a left adjoint for each category of (all algebraic structures of the same kind)." This doesn't hold, I think. For instance, if you replace "algebraic structures of the same kind" by "fields", the obvious forgetful functor $U: Fields \rightarrow Set$ does not have a left adjoint. If it did have a left adjoint $F$, we would have a bijection $Hom_{Fields}(F(\emptyset), L) \cong Hom_{Set}(\emptyset, U(L))$ for any field $L$. Such a field $F(\emptyset)$ cannot exist, however. It would be a subfield of any other field. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @M.C. Because fields of various characteristics exist. Even if we restrict to fields of a fixed characteristic ($0$ or $p$), the forgetful functor would still fail to have a left adjoint, although the initial object ($\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_{p}$) would now exist (and be free on the empty set).

Comment: @M.C. You are right, I probably meant *equationally defined* class of algebraic structures. Fields are not defined by only equations.

Comment: @Berci Alright, what do you mean by *equationally defined class of algebraic structures*? In what sense are fields not such a class?